# Android : Is it better to choose ViewwGroup then ListView for below case in android?

Tags: android, listview

I my application i need a list of items , where each item contains

1. TextView
2. ProgressBar
3. Download button
4. Cancel button

when ever i click on download button  progressBar starts and running its fine. . I have binded each row view to my data Object . In download task i.e; asynctask am using this view to update. But when am scrolling the list , progress is visible at differnt row then actual row.I dont know the reason ?

So, i decided to avoid  listview and go by creating  Viewgroup , then adding all views linearly  these views. (But i donno how to handle OnclickListens for download , button and cancel Button ) Is it good way or any other possible way to do ? performance role ? Can any one help me out these please ?

Thanking you ,

Srinivas

Answer (score 1):

How long is your list?

If < 10 items (round about, you need to check). I would switch from ListView to

- ScrollView

  - LinearLayout

    - Item 1
    - Item 2
    - Item 3

where each of your items contain the items etc. And it's still scrollable.

Then, I would attach a TAG to each ITEM and use the tag in a `onClick` handler:

```
public void handleClick(View v) {
    // use v.getTag();
}
```

Tag you can define in XML via `android:tag="1234"` or in code.

If you know what your ViewParent is (which class), then you can also CAST it to the appropriate class and get the "tag" from there.

Comment: My list is dynamic i mean . first 7 items contain each of one button , when ever i click . list grows with other set of rows .

Comment: Given the dynamic nature of your program, I would still go with my idea. As Listview is recycling views all the time it would be tedious to restore the status of each item all the time. And if your isn't that long either you might not have a huge performance problem.

Answer (score 0):

Android is heavily reusing views that comprise each slot of your ListView. As you scroll these views are getting reuse again and again so you need take care of reassigning right progress status to your items as these become hidden/visible

Said that I would actually advise against creating more than one or two AsyncTask since you will surely choke the system with too many threads.

Comment: am using onmly one asynctask .

Comment: So the reason that your progress bar is visible in the different row is because OS has pool of Views that it is reusing to paint visible portion of the list. Here's good example on how to use ViewHolder to deal with such problem http://goo.gl/nocur